# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' while seperating on the basis of space

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to separate the below column using the following code but getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Code:

```
df_no_dup["tag_count"] = df_no_dup["Tags"].apply(lambda text: len(text.split(' ')))
```

[image]

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `kaggle` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you have `None` in the `"Tags"` column so you can put an if/else in `apply` to account for that:

```
df_no_dup["tag_count"] = df_no_dup["Tags"].apply(lambda text: len(text.split(" "))
                                                              if text is not None
                                                              else 0)
```

where we put 0 in the `else` clause so `None`s will translate to 0 in `tag_count`.

But better yet, let's use `str` accessor methods `str.split` and `str.len` which will handle `None`s for us:

```
df_no_dup["tag_count"] = df_no_dup["Tags"].str.split(" ").str.len()
```

which first splits over `" "` to give lists per row and we then get the length of each list. Note, however, that this will give `NaN` as a result for `None` entries in the original series. This might be what you want; or if you want to fill them with 0, you can chain a `fillna`:

```
df_no_dup["tag_count"] = (df_no_dup["Tags"]
                              .str.split(" ")
                              .str.len()
                              .fillna(0, downcast="infer"))
```

where we fill them with 0s but also pass `downcast` so that the result won't be floats but integers which would be more meaningful for a count column. (reason it becomes float in an intermediate step is because of `NaN`(s).)

---

Yet another way is to use `str.count` with `" "` and then add 1 to the result; we count the number of spaces and then 1 more of it gives the word count:

```
df_no_dup["tag_count"] = df_no_dup["Tags"].str.count(" ").add(1)
```

Again, `None` entries will have `NaN` at the end so you can chain `fillna` as above.

Final note is that these are all considering one single whitespace; but if you want to split over possibly multiple spaces, you can pass nothing to `str.split` and it will do that by default i.e., `str.split()` and for `str.count`, you can pass the regex `r"\s+"` i.e., `str.count(r"\s+")` for multiple consecutive spaces.